# Simplest way to do grouped barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe:

```
 Catergory        Reason Species
1   Decline       Genuine      24
2  Improved       Genuine      16
3  Improved Misclassified      85
4   Decline Misclassified      41
5   Decline     Taxonomic       2
6  Improved     Taxonomic       7
7   Decline       Unclear      41
8  Improved       Unclear     117
```

I'm trying to make a grouped bar chart, species as height and then 2 colours for catergory.

here is my code:

```
Reasonstats<-read.csv("bothstats.csv")
Reasonstats2<-as.matrix(Reasonstats[,3])


barplot((Reasonstats2),beside=T,col=c("darkblue","red"),ylab="number of 
species",names.arg=Reasonstats$Reason, cex.names=0.8,las=2,space=c(0,100)
,ylim=c(0,120))
box(bty="l")
```

Now what I want, is to not have to label the two bars twice and to group them apart, I've tried changing the space value to all sorts of things and it doesn't seem to move the bars apart. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 54):

with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
Animals <- read.table(
  header=TRUE, text='Category        Reason Species
1   Decline       Genuine      24
2  Improved       Genuine      16
3  Improved Misclassified      85
4   Decline Misclassified      41
5   Decline     Taxonomic       2
6  Improved     Taxonomic       7
7   Decline       Unclear      41
8  Improved       Unclear     117')

ggplot(Animals, aes(factor(Reason), Species, fill = Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: Very useful, Thank you!

Comment: @Jack Ryan Shoul it be `ggplot(Animals, aes(factor(Reason), Species` or `ggplot(Animals, aes(factor(Reason), as.factor(Species)` ? Because in my case I hade the data like same format but it made a stack bar instead of a group bar.

Comment: As RKR pointed out, ggplot expects factors while plotting a grouped bar chart. I also had a similar data but I wasn't reading the columns as factors due to other requirements and I wasn't able to plot a grouped bar till I identified this requirement.

Answer (score 31):

Not a `barplot` solution but using `lattice`  and `barchart`:

```
library(lattice)
barchart(Species~Reason,data=Reasonstats,groups=Catergory, 
         scales=list(x=list(rot=90,cex=0.8)))
```

[image]

Comment: what about legend for colours here?

Comment: @maciek You can use `auto.key = T` within `barchart` function to have the legend.

Answer (score 29):

There are several ways to do plots in R; `lattice` is one of them, and always a reasonable solution, +1 to @agstudy.  If you want to do this in base graphics, you could try the following:

```
Reasonstats <- read.table(text="Category         Reason  Species
                                 Decline        Genuine       24
                                Improved        Genuine       16
                                Improved  Misclassified       85
                                 Decline  Misclassified       41
                                 Decline      Taxonomic        2
                                Improved      Taxonomic        7
                                 Decline        Unclear       41
                                Improved        Unclear      117", header=T)

ReasonstatsDec <- Reasonstats[which(Reasonstats$Category=="Decline"),]
ReasonstatsImp <- Reasonstats[which(Reasonstats$Category=="Improved"),]
Reasonstats3   <- cbind(ReasonstatsImp[,3], ReasonstatsDec[,3])
colnames(Reasonstats3) <- c("Improved", "Decline")
rownames(Reasonstats3) <- ReasonstatsImp$Reason

windows()
  barplot(t(Reasonstats3), beside=TRUE, ylab="number of species", 
          cex.names=0.8, las=2, ylim=c(0,120), col=c("darkblue","red"))
  box(bty="l")
```

[image]

Here's what I did: I created a matrix with two columns (because your data were in columns) where the columns were the species counts for `Decline` and for `Improved`.  Then I made those categories the column names.  I also made the `Reason`s the row names.  The `barplot()` function can operate over this matrix, but wants the data in *rows* rather than columns, so I fed it a *transposed* version of the matrix.  Lastly, I deleted some of your arguments to your `barplot()` function call that were no longer needed.  *In other words, the problem was that your data weren't set up the way* `barplot()` *wants for your intended output.*

Comment: Thanks. One advantage of using basic graphis is that you can assambly several basic plots using par() or layout().

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a function wrapper called `bar()` for `barplot()` to do what you are trying to do here, since I need to do similar things frequently. The Github link to the function is [here](https://github.com/mrxiaohe/R_Functions/blob/master/functions/bar). After copying and pasting it into R, you do

```
bar(dv = Species, 
    factors = c(Category, Reason), 
    dataframe = Reasonstats, 
    errbar = FALSE, 
    ylim=c(0, 140))  #I increased the upper y-limit to accommodate the legend.
```

The one convenience is that it will put a legend on the plot using the names of the levels in your categorical variable (e.g., "Decline" and "Improved"). If each of your levels has multiple observations, it can also plot the error bars (which does not apply here, hence `errbar=FALSE`

[image]

Comment: Where do I define the column to be used for the errorbars when using the wrapper? Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering, is there a way to stack this histogram? I want to create a three-panel figure, the first two with regular grouped bar plots as this function allows, and then the third one with each bar separated into two parts.   1/2

Comment: 2/2 -- IF I have      bar(dv = numoutspc1, 
    factors = c(Sex, Population), 
    dataframe = WALL, 
    errbar = FALSE, 
    col=c("red","purple","blue"),
    ylab=c("Number of outliers associated with each PCaxis"),
    ylim=c(0, 240))     ###but I want numoutsPC2 in each bar as well.