# How to draw a grouped barplot for two different columns?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data.frame and I would like to draw a grouped barplot for two different columns.

Below are the two columns I care about.

```
str(credit_arff)

$ checking_status       : Factor w/ 4 levels "<0",">=200","0<=X<200",..:
$ class                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "bad","good":
```

I can draw the barplot for `checking_status` by `barplot(mydata$checking_status)` (shown below) but how can I draw a barplot so that it represents how many have corresponding value of `good` or `bad`.

Ideally I would like to have different colure in each bar with each representing `good` or `bad`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot).

[QuickR](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html) is also a good reference for this sort of thing.

For your particular case, you can do this using base graphics:

```
credit_arff <- data.frame(
  checking_status = c("<0", "<0", "<0", ">=200", ">=200", "0<=X<200", "0<=X<200", "0<=X<200", "0<=X<200", "no checking", "no checking", "no checking"),
  class = c("bad", "bad", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "bad", "good", "bad", "good", "good", "bad")
)

df <- table(credit_arff$class, credit_arff$checking_status)
barplot(df, beside=T, col=c("red", "blue"), legend=rownames(df))
```

[image: your grouped bar chart]