# How to plot the amount of basket sizes in each day?

Tags: r

Here's the top 50 records of my data:

```
structure(list(Day = structure(c(2L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), BASKET_SIZE = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("L", "M", "S"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Day", "BASKET_SIZE"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Basically I have 3 basket sizes (S,M,L) and 7 days of the week (1-7). I plotted the data with `plot(e)`, and that gave me this:

[image]

So this would be good if I wanted to know the basket size dist of each day, but I'm more interested in the total amount of each basket size in each day.

---

Here's what I've tried:
`barchart(Day~BASKET_SIZE,data=e,groups=BASKET_SIZE)` based on this post: [Simplest way to do grouped barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot). But I can't seem to get the correct axis or distributions:

[image]

Also, I'd like it to be vertical, say the sum of each basket size, and have a legend showing th ecolor of each basket size. This chart that I have seems to convert my S,M,L to numbers somehow... I know it's not right because I have 3.8k rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
tt  <- t(table(dd))
barplot(as.matrix(tt),beside=TRUE)
```

?

[image]

You'd have to add the legend manually (`?legend`).

You could also do this with `ggplot2`, e.g.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd,aes(Day,fill=BASKET_SIZE))+
    geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

`ggplot` will give you legends automatically. The example here has some empty categories (e.g. no large baskets on day 1); if you want to handle that case properly, it looks like you'll have to [pre-tabulate the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834382/ggplot2-keep-unused-levels-barplot) (but if your real data set is large, that might not be a problem).