# Grouped bar plot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-visualization

For the following data.frame in R, how would I make a bar plot grouped by `Treatment Type`? The height of each bar will represent `Number of Occurrences`. `Species A` and `Species B` will be two independent bars plotted adjacent to each other.

```
`Treatment Type`      Species    `Number of Occurrences`
         <chr>         <chr>                    <dbl>
Treatment           Species A                    10
Control             Species A                    15
Treatment           Species B                    55
Control             Species B                     5
```

Comment: I see one numeric variable and two potential grouping variables. Can you elaborate what bar plot you wish to achieve?

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). Furthermore, please also read: [ask]

Comment: @KarstenW. We were asked to make a grouped bar graph in R using this information. Thankyou for the quick reply!

Comment: @Sahar you must always produce a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by "group", you meant the binary variable `Type`, I have the following two solutions for you, using `lattice` and `ggplot2` packages, respectively:

Before plotting, I reconstituted a (limited version of?) your data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Type = rep(c("Treatment", "Control"), 2),
  Species = c(rep("Species A", 2), rep("Species B", 2)),
  Number_of_Occurrences = c(10, 15, 55, 5)
)
df
# Type   Species Number_of_Occurrences
# 1 Treatment Species A                    10
# 2   Control Species A                    15
# 3 Treatment Species B                    55
# 4   Control Species B                     5
```

First method: `lattice` package:

```
library(lattice)
barchart(
  Number_of_Occurrences~Species,
  data=df, groups=Type, 
  scales=list(x=list(rot=90,cex=0.8))
)
```

[image]

Second method, `ggplot2` package; you will need to reformat the data.frame using `reshape::melt` function to meet the requirement of `ggplot2`

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
df.m <- melt(df)
df.m
# Type   Species              variable value
# 1 Treatment Species A Number_of_Occurrences    10
# 2   Control Species A Number_of_Occurrences    15
# 3 Treatment Species B Number_of_Occurrences    55
# 4   Control Species B Number_of_Occurrences     5
ggplot(df.m, aes(Species, value, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Reference: [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot).

Comment: Thankyou!!! I used the lattice packagae. When I try to go in and add the x and change the y labels it will not let me. I used xlab and ylab.

Comment: This works for me: `barchart(
  Number_of_Occurrences~Species,
  data=df, groups=Type, 
  xlab = "Species", ylab="Number of Occurrences",
  scales=list(x=list(rot=90,cex=0.8))
)`

Comment: If you decided to use `ggplot2`, append the `xlab()` and `ylab`: `ggplot(df.m, aes(Species, value, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  ylab("Number of Occurrences")`

Comment: Thankyou! I used the lattice package. I have another question(sorry for all of these questions!). if i need to make a bar graph of the mean of three different orders of mammals, how would I do that in R? I tried everything I could think of. I calculated the mean for all of them, but I do not know where to go from there.

Comment: You can make a data.frame with a column `mean` and/or other summary statistics. Then, plot this new data.frame using one of the barplot methods as before. If you're unfamiliar with how to make data.frames, check out this post http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame

Comment: I did this:x=as.data.frame(cbind(meanmammals))
barchart(x) but the barchart did not make an order nor did it show the means? I am very new to R.