# Error In Bar plot - incorrect number of names

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm having trouble creating bar plots in R. The odd thing is that I've used the same script before with different variables without any issues, so I don't really know what is going on (I'm fairly new to R).

The code I've been using is (with transposed matrix):

```
barplot(StandtF, main="h2, c2, e2 by Mod FEMALES",
xlab="Social Support", ylab="% of Var", beside=TRUE, axesnames=TRUE,
names.arg=c("No","Yes"),
col=c("red","green","darkblue"))
    legend("topleft",c("h2","c2","e2"),fill=c("red","green","darkblue") )
```

And the error message that's returned is:

> Error in barplot.default(StandtM, main = "h2, c2, e2 by Mod FEMALES",
>   xlab = "Social Support",  : 
>       incorrect number of names
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) :
>       "axesnames" is not a graphical parameter

I've looked around at different posts, but nothing so far has been helpful. And as said, the script has worked fine previously.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have answered your question, nevertheless it would be helpful if you provide how does your data look like.

Comment: You have a 'typo' in your code: use `axisnames = TRUE` in stead of `axes....`

Answer (score 1):

You gave to the function two names `names.arg=c("No","Yes")`and you have three levels according to your legend and the colors defined.
So, you need a vector with three names.

Comment: I'm trying to create a grouped bar plot. I have values for h2, c2 and e2 under both yes and no. Below is the output from my script:

Comment: h2m
0.2213663
c2m
0.004542067
e2m
 0.7740917
h2mM
0.2408153
c2mM
0.00546826
e2mM
0.7537164
 
h2f
0.4621275
c2f
0.0985327
e2f
0.4393398
h2fM
0.4838181
c2fM
0.1024018
e2fM
0.4137801
This is what I'm trying to plot, with h2fM, c2fM, and e2fM being categorised at 'yes'

Comment: The way you displayed the information doesn't help to see how data looks like. If I have understood well your question, this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot