# How to show number of occurrences on Y axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a grouped bar chart in R using ggplot2. Code I'm using for that is:

```
ggplot(loanData, aes(factor(loanData$saving_status), <Y AXIS ATTRIBUTE>, fill = loanData$class)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

However, I don't know what should I replace "Y AXIS ATTRIBUTE" with in order to indicate number of occurrences for values of *saving_status* and *class* attributes on the chart. I guess what I need is to count those occurrences using some method and put the result there?

Basically what I'm looking for is something like answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot) but I don't have value in my table I could use in the same way as "species" is used in that example. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to input y for count of x. just change value of stat to count/bin.

try following:

```
ggplot(loanData, aes(factor(loanData$saving_status),fill = loanData$class)) +
geom_bar(stat="count", position = "dodge") + 
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

please provide sample data to help you better.

Comment: that did the trick! I'm new to R and still trying to grasp the syntax, etc. thank you so much