# Grouped bar chart: ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data.

What I am trying to do is first sort and match the columns `Feature1`, `Feature2`, and `Feature3` to follow the same order as the first column `Feature`, with their corresponding numbers.

`Feature` corresponds to `LastYear`

`Feature1` corresponds to `OneYear`

`Feature2` corresponds to `TwoYear`

`Feature3` corresponds to `ThreeYear`

So taking the `Feature1` and its corresponding `OneYear` column, the values for `logTA = 0.32627....` would drop down to `row 2` since `logTA` is in `row 2` in the `Feature` column. The `CA.CL = 0.16196....` would drop to `row 6` etc.

The the same would apply to `Feature 2` and `Feature 3`. All sorted based on being matched with the `Feature` column.

****** Maybe the above part is not needed.

Secondly I want to `melt` the data frame, grouping by `LastYear`, `OneYear`, `TwoYear` and `ThreeYear`.

So the idea is to then plot something similar to the following;

[image]

Where, `Food`, `Music` and `People` would be replaced with `LastYear`, `OneYear`, `TwoYear` and `ThreeYear`. Also the bars would correspond to `CA.CL`, `logTA` etc.

```
structure(list(Feature = structure(c(6L, 8L, 5L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 9L), .Label = c("CA.CL", "CA.TA", "CF.NCL", 
"CL.FinExp", "DailySALES.EBIT", "EBIT.FinExp", "EQ.Turnover", 
"logTA", "SALES.WC", "TL.EQ", "TL.TA"), class = "factor"), LastYear = structure(c(11L, 
10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0322326139141556", 
"0.0418476895487213", "0.0432506289654195", "0.0504153839825875", 
"0.0546743268879608", "0.0549979876321639", "0.0577181189006888", 
"0.107473282590142", "0.112929456881545", "0.139817111427972", 
"0.304643399268643"), class = "factor"), Feature1 = structure(c(8L, 
6L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("CA.CL", 
"CA.TA", "CF.NCL", "CL.FinExp", "DailySALES.EBIT", "EBIT.FinExp", 
"EQ.Turnover", "logTA", "SALES.WC", "TL.EQ", "TL.TA"), class = "factor"), 
    OneYear = structure(c(11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0241399538457295", "0.025216904130219", 
    "0.0288943827773218", "0.0290134083108585", "0.0393919110672302", 
    "0.0484816627329215", "0.0660812827117713", "0.0728943625765924", 
    "0.161968277822423", "0.177638448005797", "0.326279406019136"
    ), class = "factor"), Feature2 = structure(c(8L, 1L, 6L, 
    9L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 7L), .Label = c("CA.CL", "CA.TA", 
    "CF.NCL", "CL.FinExp", "DailySALES.EBIT", "EBIT.FinExp", 
    "EQ.Turnover", "logTA", "SALES.WC", "TL.EQ", "TL.TA"), class = "factor"), 
    TwoYear = structure(c(11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0179871842234001", "0.0245082857218191", 
    "0.0276514285623367", "0.0359182021377123", "0.0461243809893583", 
    "0.046996298679094", "0.0566018025811507", "0.0648203522637183", 
    "0.0815346014308433", "0.210073355633034", "0.387784107777533"
    ), class = "factor"), Feature3 = structure(c(8L, 1L, 11L, 
    7L, 9L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 10L), .Label = c("CA.CL", "CA.TA", 
    "CF.NCL", "CL.FinExp", "DailySALES.EBIT", "EBIT.FinExp", 
    "EQ.Turnover", "logTA", "SALES.WC", "TL.EQ", "TL.TA"), class = "factor"), 
    ThreeYear = structure(c(11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0.0275302883400183", "0.0282746857626618", 
    "0.0403110592712779", "0.0409053619122674", "0.0514576931772448", 
    "0.0570216362435987", "0.076967996046118", "0.0831531609222676", 
    "0.0904194376665785", "0.139457271733071", "0.364501408924896"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Feature", "LastYear", 
"Feature1", "OneYear", "Feature2", "TwoYear", "Feature3", "ThreeYear"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### EDIT:

```
feature_suffix <- c("", "1", "2", "3")
year_prefix <- c("Last", "One", "Two", "Three")

x <- map2(feature_suffix, year_prefix,
     ~ df %>% 
       select(feature = paste0("Feature", .x), value = paste0(.y, "Year")) %>%
       mutate(year = paste0(.y, "Year"))
) %>%
  bind_rows(.) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value))

xy <- x %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  arrange(year, desc(value)) 

ggplot(data = xy, aes(year, value, fill=feature)) +
geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y=mean, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to do grouped barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rearrange into long format, then plotting is straightforward.
Here's a way to do that using `purrr:map2()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

feature_suffix <- c("", "1", "2", "3")
year_prefix <- c("Last", "One", "Two", "Three")

map2(feature_suffix, year_prefix,
     ~ df %>% 
       select(feature = paste0("Feature", .x), value = paste0(.y, "Year")) %>%
       mutate(year = paste0(.y, "Year"))
) %>%
  bind_rows(.) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, fill=feature)) +
  geom_bar(stat="summary", fun.y=mean, position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks thats more or less what I wanted! two things, I do not fully understand the code, is it possible to order the bars based on highest to lowest for each year? How can I add text inside the bars vertically? I know these things can be done, just cannot see how I can fit them into the code. But thanks again! Its what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome!  Any ordering you want to do can be done after the mapping.  Just create a `df`, like: `df <- map2(...) ... mutate(...)` (stop before you pipe to `ggplot`).  Now it's just a regular data frame.  (I am assuming you know how to order values within groups for plotting - if not there are plenty of other posts on this topic, or you can open a new question if you can't find what you're looking for.)  As for understanding `purrr::map()`, it's just the tidyverse version of the `apply` family in base R.  Here are the docs for [`map2()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am trying what you have suggested. I have stopped just before the pipe `ggplot` ordered the values by groups using `dplyr` but the `ggplot` I am getting is still the same as you provided (the order within groups do not change) - I edited my original post and posted the code.

Comment: Please note in my earlier comment: you still need to perform your desired grouping/ordering operations on your own, assigning to do just breaks the pipe so you can make changes before plotting. (You can do it within the pipeline too, if needed.) This is really a separate topic from your original post though, it's more appropriate for a second post. Or just search for the many posts already existing that show how to order within groupings for ggplot bar graphs.