# Create Grouped Bar Chart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'd like to create a grouped bar chart showing poverty rates in 4 different regions (Northeast, Midwest, West, and South)for US vs foreign born workers. I am unsure how to create the output I'm looking for in R with ggplot. I have included below the code I've attempted, as well as a fake bar graph I created in Excel to give a sense of what I'm looking for.

My first 4 lines of code are computing the poverty rate percents for each region. And I know I also need to sort people into US vs foreign born buckets, which I tried to do with the variables I created beforehand for whether someone is US or foreign born.

I'm not sure how to compile this into a final code with ggplot.. Thank you!

```
perc_poverty_Northeast=sum((US_born_Northeast$POVERTY)/nrow(US_born_Northeast))*100 
perc_poverty_Midwest=sum((US_born_Midwest$POVERTY)/nrow(US_born_Midwest))*100 
perc_poverty_South=sum((US_born_South$POVERTY)/nrow(US_born_South))*100 

region=c(West,Midwest,South,Northeast)

Immigrant_region=c(Immigrant_West,Immigrant_Midwest,Immigrant_South,Immigrant_Northeast)
US_born_region=c(US_born_West,US_born_Midwest,US_born_South,US_born_Northeast)

ggplot(NHIS1,aes(fill=region, y=perc_poverty, x=c(Immigrant_region, US_born_region)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Perhaps this already does what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot

Comment: With the exception of the error bars (more than you asked for), the barplot examples at https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar.html does exactly what you need here, with usable sample data and working code.